# How to move body of a table into to another component, so it won't break styling

Tags: angular, html-table, components, primeng, ng-template

I have a pretty large table component and I want to separate its body section into new component. Each time I am trying to do this, the styling of table gets broken (because of new HTML structure in the code I think) I am using angular 5.

I have tried to create a new component with the code that was actually inside of a body section in the original table, but the UI is rendered in the terrible fashion, does not look good at all. Columns are broken, checkbnoxes as well. I think that ngPrime styles are not working, well I am quite sure about it.

Original code:

```
<p-table 
         [value]="data"
         ...
>
  <ng-template  pTemplate="body" let-row let-expanded="expanded" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <tr class="cursor-pointer" 
        [pContextMenuRow]="row"
        [pSelectableRow]="row"
        [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex">

      <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="{{col.styleClass}}">
        <span class="ui-column-title">{{col.header}}</span>
        <p-checkbox
          *ngIf="shouldShowCheckbox()"
          binary="true"
          [disabled]="!isEditable"
          (onChange)="toggle($event, col.field, rowIndex)">
        </p-checkbox>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>


</p-table>
```

---

My code in html file:

```
<tr class="cursor-pointer"
    [pContextMenuRow]="row"
    [pSelectableRow]="row"
    [pSelectableRowIndex]="rowIndex">

  <td *ngFor="let col of columns" class="{{col.styleClass}}">
    <span class="ui-column-title">{{col.header}}</span>
    <p-checkbox
      *ngIf="shouldShowCheckbox()"
      binary="true"
      [disabled]="!isEditable"
      (onChange)="toggle($event, col.field, rowIndex)">
    </p-checkbox>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My code in TS file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-body',
  template: './table-body.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-body.component.scss']
})
export class TableBodyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() columns: any[];
  @Input() row: any;
  @Input() rowIndex: number;
  @Input() isEditable: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Table after my refactoring:

```
<p-table 
         [value]="data"
         ...
>
  <ng-template  pTemplate="body" let-row let-expanded="expanded" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
    <table-body [columns]="columns"
                [row]="row"
                [rowIndex]="rowIndex"
                [isEditable]="isEditable"
    ></table-body>
  </ng-template>


</p-table>
```

As a result I would like to have exactly this same page after this refactiring. Does anyone know how to pass styling to this new child component, or how to make this ng styling work again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an attribute selector with the component.

So you would use the component like this:

```
<p-table [value]="data">
  <ng-template  ...>
    <tr table-body ...></tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

You would then define the selector like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tr[table-body]',
  ...
})
```

Inside the template you'll no longer have access to the `<td>` tag, but the component has the `host` binding that allow you to change the classes or styles from the component.

https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#host